# Activcate a python virtual environment from a linux bash script

Tags: python, linux, bash, python-venv

I am writing a bash script in linux that creates and activates a Python venv and then installs from a requirements.txt. Like this

```
python3 -m venv ~/myvenv/env
source ~/myvenv/env/bin/activate
cp requirements.txt ~/myvenv/env/requirements.txt
pip3 install -r ~/myvenv/env/requirements.txt
```

This doesn't work for me. It seems to create the myvenv directory but then doesnt switch in and run the requirements.txt file.

Is there a different way to activate it with `source` from within a bash script?

Comment: While what you have should work, you don't actually need to activate. You can just call pip inside the venv directly. `python3 -m venv ~/myvenv/env; ~/myvenv/env/bin/pip3 install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: Thanks for that, I was not aware that I did not need to active. That is a lot quicker now thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you run script your shell spawns new process, activates it and then dies.
That's why when you get back into your shell you see unactivated one.

you can run your script just using source command. source command will load it into your active shell.

```
source script.sh
```